# XML Schema, Including standalone information in the header and repeating rows

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Input File

```
Kontonummer Datum   Betrag  Ratenzahl   Ratenart    Vorname Nachname    Geschlecht  Geburtsdatum    Strasse PLZ Ort
1234    30/10/1994  Test1   Hello1  Testing1    George  Brown   Male    30/10/1985  Street 1    2   Test 1
1235    30/10/1995  Test2   Hello2  Testing2    John    Dwayne  Male    30/10/1986  Street 2    3   Test 2
1236    30/10/1996  Test3   Hello3  Testing3    Tony    Jim Male    30/10/1987  Street 3    3   Test 3
1237    30/10/1997  Test4   Hello4  Testing4    Bill    Tony    Male    30/10/1988  Street 4    4   Test 4
1238    30/10/1998  Test5   Hello5  Testing5    Bob George  Male    30/10/1989  Street 5    4   Test 5
1239    30/10/1999  Test6   Hello6  Testing6    Robert  Brad    Male    30/10/1990  Street 6    5   Test 6
1240    30/10/2000  Test7   Hello7  Testing7    Brad    Sean    Male    30/10/1991  Street 7    5   Test 7
1241    30/10/2001  Test8   Hello8  Testing8    Sean    Paul    Male    30/10/1992  Street 8    6   Test 8
1242    30/10/2002  Test9   Hello9  Testing9    Paul    George  Male    30/10/1993  Street 9    6   Test 9
```

I am using the below XSD that I have created to map XML elements in excel. The problem is, at the moment when saving the excel as xml it only takes one record of data and populates the xml with this when in fact there are 10 rows of data.

When I save the file as xml I want

```
  xsd:element name="SchufaService_Version" type="xsd:string" fixed="2.0"/>
```

and

```
   <xsd:element name="Data_Language" type="xsd:string" fixed="DEU"/>
```

to appear in the header but at the moment this is not being displayed. Can you please advise?

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="TestingRecord" type="TestingRecord"/>
  <xsd:element name="TestingService_Version" type="xsd:string" fixed="2.0"/>
  <xsd:element name="Data_Language" type="xsd:string" fixed="DEU"/>  

  <xsd:complexType name="SchufaRecord">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Merkdermal" type="Merkdermal"/>
      <xsd:element name="Verbraucherdaten" type="Verbraucherdaten"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Merkdermal">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Kontonummer"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Datum" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Betrag"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Ratenzahl" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Ratenart"   type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Verbraucherdaten">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Vorname"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Nachname" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Geschlecht"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Geburtsdatum" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="AktuelleAdresse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Strasse"   type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="PLZ" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Ort"   type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element> 
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Testing version="2.0">
  <Data language="DEU">
    <Aktion teilnehmerkennung="123/45678" teilnehmerkennwort="SECURE07">
      <MeldungVertragsdaten version="1.0">
        <Meldemerkmal merkmalcode="BU">
          <Kontonummer>655544454</Kontonummer>
          <Datum>03052010</Datum>
          <Betrag waehrung="EUR">50000</Betrag>
          <Ratenzahl>84</Ratenzahl>
          <Ratenart>M</Ratenart>
        </Meldemerkmal>
        <Meldeart>neumeldung</Meldeart>
        <Verbraucherdaten>
          <Vorname>Geiz</Vorname>
          <Nachname>Heinz</Nachname>
          <Geschlecht>m</Geschlecht>
          <Geburtsdatum>13051970</Geburtsdatum>
          <AktuelleAdresse>
            <Strasse>Am Hello 1</Strasse>
            <PLZ>60437</PLZ>
            <Ort>Denmark</Ort>
          </AktuelleAdresse>
        </Verbraucherdaten>
       </MeldungVertragsdaten>
    </Aktion>
  </Data>
</Testing>
```

Comment: You'll get better answers if it's easier to reproduce your problem.  If you provide some sample input (you say you have a ten-line input file, that might do nicely, in CSV form), the output you're getting, and the output you want, it might be possible to reproduce and solve the problem.  (You may also need to describe more precisely how you specify the mapping, if it's not obvious to an Excel user.)  As it is, no one can do more than speculate about what is going wrong for you.

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback on how I could improve my post. I have included the edits.

Comment: Too many contradictions among prose, schema, and XML. You say you want the elements
`<SchufaService_Version>2.0</SchufaService_Version>` and
`<Data_Language>DEU</Data_Language>` in your output, but your sample output lacks them. The schema declares no
`SchufaService_Version` element; the `TestingService_Version` and
`Data_Language` it does declare are not allowed as children of any
other element in the schema.  And your sample output has only
sporadic similarities to the schema. I recommend [a good XSD tutorial](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/).